# Strange App Icon behaviour

Tags: android, mipmaps

I have replaced the standard android studio app icon (ic_launcher) with my own(one for each dimension in the mipmap folders) and deleted the ic_launcher round icons since i won't be using round icons on my app. The problem is that although the icons show up correctly in the res->mipmap->ic_launcher folder, when i install the app on my phone the app's icon is the default one and not the one i chose. Also, if you go into tje phone's app info, the app's icon shows up correctly. I have no clue on why this is happening. Any idea?

Comment: maybe the phone launcher caches the icon when it shouldn't. So you still see the old icon from the cache.

Comment: remove roundicon from application tag and use icon to show icon you want

Comment: @Henry it's actually an issue with Nova Launcher, thank you for helping me figure that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to manifest and look for roundicon and dont forget to change there.

Comment: I've deleted it, is that ok?

Comment: have you removed roundicon line from manifest? @SteliosPapamichael

Comment: Yes i have removed it

Answer (score 0):

Go to manifest and replace default icon name with yours here:

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"